# template parameter redeclaration

Tags: c++, templates

This is what I want to achieve. The leaf component will inherit `Component<ParentT>`, others will inherit `Component<ParentT, ChildT>`

```
template <typename T>
class Component{
  protected:
    typedef Component<T> ParentComponentT;
  ...
};

template <typename ParentT, typename ChildT>
class Component: public Component<ParentT>{
  protected:
    typedef std::vector<ChildT*> CollectionT;
  ...
};
```

But the problem is Template parameters getting redeclared. and I cannot move the second one above first one because second one inherits first one.

> error: redeclared with 2 template parameter(s)
>   note: previous declaration ‘template class Component’ used 1 template parameter(s)

Comment: Ignoring variadic templates for the moment, templates have a fixed number of parameters; a single `Component<>` cannot have both one and two parameters. This very much looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166663) -- what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Then What is the good way to model it ? `Component <T, void>` ?

Comment: That depends -- why do you want the base and the child to have the same name? Give them different type names and you have no issue.

Comment: Yes I don't want to give a different name. So is having a completely different definition in `Component <T, void>` (such as having different methods and typedefs etc..) may be an option. but Is it the only option ?

Comment: Yep, pretty much (though it would help if you said _why_ you don't want to give them different names that might help; again, XY problem).

Comment: @ildjarn. Template argument can have default type arguments. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @Johan : I never said otherwise -- you still have two template parameters, whether you specify both or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compiles and as far as I understand does what you like:

```
#include <vector>

class NoneT {};

template <typename ParentT,typename ChildT=NoneT>
class Component: public Component<ParentT>{
  protected:
    typedef std::vector<ChildT*> CollectionT;
};
```

Specialization for `NoneT`:

```
template<>
template<typename T>
class Component<T,NoneT>{
protected:
   typedef Component<T> ParentComponentT;
};

int main(){
   typedef Component<double> someT;
   typedef Component<double,int> someT2;
   typedef Component<double,void> someT3;
}
```

`someT` will have `ParentComponentT` and `someT2` will have `CollectionT`.

**EDIT:**

Answer to comment/question below: `typename ChildT=noneT` means that the default `ChildT` will be `noneT`. So, if no second template argument is given the `noneT` type will be used.

The specialization then defines the class content for the that one-argument version.

**EDIT2:**

Since I know from the chat that you use Component as a base class, I suggest that instead of something like

```
class myclass: public Component<Section, Line>
```

you could use multiple inheritance

```
class myclass: public ParentComponent<Section>, CollectionComponent<Line>
```

with

```
template <typename T>
class ParentComponent{
  protected:
    typedef Component<T> ParentComponentT;
};

template <typename ChildT>
class CollectionComponent {
  protected:
    typedef std::vector<ChildT*> CollectionT;
};
```

Comment: why `ChildT=NoteT` or `ChildT=void` if first template ?You are specializing it in the second on

Comment: if no second template argument is given it will go to the second version of template. why would it look for the default parameter ?

Comment: That's how the language works. The second argument has a default parameter and that's valid throughout. The specialization determines what will happen for that particular type.

Comment: mine compiles with `void` why should I use `NoneT` ?

Comment: Neel Basu, Yes that works but that would make your class fail if you actually wanted to use the void type as second argument. From the code you posted that is not an impossible case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14912/discussion-between-johan-lundberg-and-neel-basu)